# Integrate Twilio Voice with iOS swift - Twilio CLI to deploy access token

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, twilio, twilio-api

According to documentation [refered](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/ios/get-started#bullet1), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k51He.png)
The info doesn't stored in key-chain and also not created any "Server" folder in root directory.

I've installed node.js, npm and logged-in to twilio with SID through terminal, now try to do this step [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkbBj.png) but terminal shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COuLC.png)